# gwt client session time out

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-ext, gwt-platform

I am using gwt 2.3 with gwtp framework.In this application I wan to maintain a session time of 5 mins.This means if current user is not doing up to 5 min and he comes after five min then on his first event/action on screen a he should be be logged out.
In gwt there is class named Timer which can be used in this issues.But I am not getting how to recognize action of user on the screen.I did google on it, & found the code for gwt-ext.Below is the code of gwt-ext

```
Ext.get(“pagePanel”).addListener(“click”, new EventCallback() {
    @Override
    public void execute(EventObject e) {
        MessageBox.alert(“On Mouse Click”);
    }
});

Ext.get(“pagePanel”).addListener(“keydown”, new EventCallback() {

    @Override
    public void execute(EventObject e) { 
        MessageBox.alert(“On Key Press Click”);
    }
});
```

In above code tag in working properly so I am attaching link from where I got this code.[here](http://coffeewithcode.com/2011/07/08/how-to-get-an-event-of-a-page-in-gwt/)

Same type of code I am looking in gwt.If there any other better way to do this then please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If action/event can be really everythin, I would solve it with a 
`NativePreviewHandler` in the following way:

```
boolean expired;

final Timer logoutTimer = new Timer() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        expired = true;
    }
};

NativePreviewHandler nph = new NativePreviewHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        if (!expired) {
            logoutTimer.cancel();
            logoutTimer.schedule(300000);
        } else {
            // do your logout stuff here
        }
    }
};

Event.addNativePreviewHandler(nph);
```

If the user shell be logged out without a new action after 5 minutes:

```
final Timer logoutTimer = new Timer() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your logout stuff here
    }
};

NativePreviewHandler nph = new NativePreviewHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        // Of course do this only when logged in:
        logoutTimer.cancel();
        logoutTimer.schedule(300000);
    }
};

Event.addNativePreviewHandler(nph);
```

Comment: @Is there any other way to handle client side session